# Android. Making a synchronous Request with RequestFuture get() and AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, httprequest, android-volley, synchronous

i think i need some help with android volley. I am trying to make a simple HTTP request and wait for the response, because i need the response data for further processing. I have been trying for three days now, but wasn't able to get it done yet.

Basically i want to click a button -> make a request -> get a response -> handle it -> make a new request depending on the previous response -> handle the secon response -> and then show the results on my activity.

Is started the request in an AsysncTask as recommended but it always times out without response. I hope you can help me.

```
public class Connection extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String>{

private static RequestQueue queue;

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
    String response = null;
    Context context = (Context) params[0];
    String url = (String) params[1];

    queue = getQueue(context.getApplicationContext());

    RequestFuture<String> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, future, future);
    queue.add(request);

    try {
        response = future.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return response;
}

private static RequestQueue getQueue(Context context) {
    if (queue == null) {
        queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return queue;
}
```

}

The call is started from an extra Thread:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public synchronized void start() {
        super.start();
        String url = UrlRequestGenerator.buildUrl(originLat, originLong, context); // context from calling activity
        try {
            response = new HAFASConnection().execute(context, url).get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(response);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I did that recently but in the same thread. You could check first in the same thread if it works. If it doesn't, it means it could come from your url.

```
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getBaseContext());
        String url ="http://....";

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        finish();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyError r = error;
            }
        });
        queue.add(stringRequest);
```

If it goes on onErrorResponse, check your url and your server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the problem is not the url or the extra Thread. I chekced this multiple times.
I seems that     response = future.get()  (Times out every time) blocks forever and i can not determine why.

Comment: Error Message = Skipped 304 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. 
I am wondering why i get this message, because i started the extra thread to avoid this.

Comment: For the 304 frames: https://vaibhavtolia.wordpress.com/2013/10/03/79/ but why you thread here ? You are already starting an AsyncTask

Comment: The link tells me to start a new Thread, because of heavy work.
My AsyncTask blocks the whole GUI Thread, because the get() Method blocks forever. Because of that i start the asyncTask from a new Thread to leave alone the gui thread waiting for the response.
I tried to start the AsyncTask from the main Thread, but got the same Problem.